# Nodejs: I want to know how to redirect to last page with scroll position

Tags: nodes

I have a issue after adding items to cart.
After adding items to cart my code is
res.redirect('back'); ---> it is taking me to last page. But what I need is redirect to last page and last item(scroll position) that user clicked.

Thanks in Advanceslightly_smiling_face.